# Function returning decimal, results in "Arithmetic overflow error"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function that accepts two parameters, gets the total number of records, gets the total value of the "RecordValue" field, and then returns a calculated average.  This is the same way that you get any "average" number... (Total / Number of Records = Average).

```
DECLARE @RecordCount INT = 0
DECLARE @RecordTotal INT = 0
DECLARE @RecordAverage DECIMAL(3,2) = 0.00

SET @RecordCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <query here>)

SET @RecordTotal = (SELECT SUM(RecordValue) FROM <query here>)  

SET @RecordAverage = (CAST(@RecordCount AS DECIMAL(5,2))) / (CAST(@RecordTotal AS DECIMAL(5,2)))
```

Now, If I run SCRIPT FUNCTION AS > SELECT TO in SQL Server Management Studio, it gives me a valid decimal, which when ran for the first record that I'm looking for, returns 9.75.

My stored procedure calls this function and passes it the two required parameters, which is what I used "manually" when running the function by itself:

```
SELECT dbo.MyFunctionThatReturnsAnAverage(RecordTypeId, RecordCategory) AS 'Returned Average'
    FROM <query here>
```

Yet, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. (line 53)
```

Line 53 is the SELECT statement.  All variables are declared correctly, and the decimals are DECIMAL(5,2).  Without having to post the huge query that's being done (lots of joins and whatnot), does anyone see something wrong with how I'm calculating this average?

Comment: What datatype is `RecordValue`? What does `SCRIPT FUNCTION AS > SELECT TO` mean?

Comment: RecordValue is an INT.  So within the function, let's say that there were 2 records, one with a RecordValue of 2 and the other with a RecordValue of 7.  (7 + 2) / 2 = 4.5.   So when I CAST each of those as DECIMAL, it should return 4.50 as the answer.  This works fine when I run the function by itself (by manually entering RecordTypeId and RecordCategory into it).  But when I run the stored procedure (which calls the function), I get that error.